# Error installing Data.Aeson

Tags: haskell, aeson

Hello can anyone tell me how can i install the `Data.Aeson` package?I am running into the following error:

```
WARNING: cache is out WoAfR NdaItNeG::  Cc:a/cUhsee riss/ aodurti aonf.b edrcaotev:i ciC/:Ap/pUDsaeta/rLso/caadlr/iParno.gbrearmcso/vsitcaic/kA/pxp8D6a_t6a4/-Lwoicnadlo/ws/Pgrhocg-r8a.ms0./2s\ltiabc\kp/xack8a6g_e6.4c-ownfi.ndd\poawcsk/agghec.-c8a.c0h.e2
\glhicb \wpialclk asgeee. caonn fo.ldd\ pvaicekwa goef. ctahcihse
pgahcck awgiel ld bs.e eU saen  'oglhdc -vpikegw  roefc atchhies'  ptaoc kfaigxe.
db. Use 'ghc-pkg recache' to fix.
Error parsing targets: Directory not found: Data.Aeson
```

Below it says `Use ghc-pkg recache`.When i try running this command i get the following error:

```
ghc-pkg.exe: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.4.2\lib\package.conf.d\package.cache: you don't have permission to modify this file
```

I have tried installing `Data.Aeson` both with `cabal install Data.Aeson` and with `Stack install Data.Aeson`.With the latter i get the following error:

```
WARNING:WA caRcNhIeN Gi:s  coaucth eo fi sd oautte :o fC :d/aUtsee:r sC/a:d/riaUns.ebresr/caodvriicain/.AbpeprDcatova/Lioccia/lA/pPprDoagtraa/mLso/csatla/cPkr/oxg8r6a_m6s4/-swtiancdko/wxs8/6g_h6c4--8w.i0n.d2o\wlsi/bg\hpca-c8k.a0g.e2.\cloinbf\.pda\cpkaacgkea.gceo.ncfa.cdh\ep
agchkca gwei.lcla csheee
 gahnc  owlidl lv iseewe  oafn  tohlids  vpiaecwk aogfe  tdhbi.s  Upsaec k'agghec -dpbk.g  Urseec a'cghhec'- ptkog  friexc.a
che' to fix.
Error parsing targets: Directory not found: Data.Aeson
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Data.Aeson` is not a package, it is one of many modules within the package called `aeson`.  Try `cabal install aeson`.